# clearInterval and $interval not working in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, setinterval

I have a RightSidebarLayout Page in my Angular application,where i have setup an interval `setInterval` and called a function on it,for getting an notification from the factory function.

The problem is that I want to clear it after the user has logged Out.

Here is my code `RightSidebarLayout.Controller.js`

The first thing I tried is that I used `setInterval` method using plain javascript, but I got an error of `ToastInterval not defined`

```
var vm = this;
function init(){
   var ToastInterval = setInterval(getAllNotifications, 9000); // when user has logged out stop my interval
        }
init();

function getAllNotifications() {
  //    alert(commonApi.IsUserLoggedIn()) // alerts true if logged in else false //working properly
     if (!IsUserLoggedIn()){
        clearInterval(ToastInterval);  // This shows error ToastInterval is undefined as i have defined it in parent environment
          return;
     }
     else {
       notificationService.getNoti() // Call a service and get all notification 
     }
  }
```

My question here is why i am not getting the `ToastInterval` as it is declared in its `lexical environment`,,,

2) So I used my `ControllerAs` to defined by `$Interval` callback ,it doesn't gave me error ,still its not working, it still fires function

```
var vm = this;
function init(){
   vm.ToastInterval = $interval(getAllNotifications, 9000); // when user has logged out stop my interval
}
init();

function getAllNotifications() {
   //    alert(commonApi.IsUserLoggedIn()) // alerts true if logged in else false //working properly
   if (!IsUserLoggedIn()){
        $interval.cancel(vm.ToastInterval);
        return;
    }
    else {
       notificationService.getNoti() // Call a service and get all notification 
      }
  }
```

Here the interval is not cleared even though I get the alert my interval is not cleared..

What I'm doing wrong?

Please help,

Comment: But it is my lexical environment..also why my second thing not working

Comment: You are getting the error `ToastInterval not defined` as it is defined inside the function `init`. Declare the variable `ToastInterval` where the variable `vm` is declared and your code will work.

Comment: Yes my second code,my vm is global, then also its not working

Comment: your variables is not global. Variable declared in function will be available to only that function.

Comment: but it is accessible to child function or closures

Comment: Did you try after calling `$interval.cancel(vm.ToastInterval);` set `vm.ToastInterval = undefined;` ?

Comment: Why should i do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change the first code to

JS:

```
  var vm = this,
      ToastInterval;
  function init(){
    ToastInterval = setInterval(getAllNotifications, 9000); // when user has logged out stop my interval
  }
  init();

  function getAllNotifications() {
        //    alert(commonApi.IsUserLoggedIn()) // alerts true if logged in else false //working properly
            if (!IsUserLoggedIn()){
                clearInterval(ToastInterval);  // This shows error ToastInterval is undefined as i have defined it in parent environment
                return;
            }
            else {
              notificationService.getNoti() // Call a service and get all notification 
            }
        }
```

I have decalred the variable `ToastInterval`outside the init function.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle so that it can be debugged further.

Comment: It worked but still i am not getting,why my this,variable did not worked